# ADAL query security groups

Tags: c#, rest, azure-active-directory, adal

I have a system that logs into a native wpf app via an web api on azure.

```
AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(string.Format("https://login.windows.net/{0}", authority));
AuthenticationResult tokenAuthResult = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientId, new Uri(redirectUri), new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Auto)).Result;

if (tokenAuthResult == null) return;          

Credentials.RestCredentials = new TokenCredentials(tokenAuthResult.AccessToken);

Credentials.UserName = string.Concat(tokenAuthResult.UserInfo.GivenName, " ", tokenAuthResult.UserInfo.FamilyName);
```

This all works perfect, with returning token etc.
The users are all in ADAL, and have associated groups against them (these are all O365 users).
I want to be able to query what the logged in users associated group(s) are.
Do I need to make a new call out using the Graph api?
Do I use the returned token?
I'm a little lost here.
Thanks in advance 
Scott

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way is to go to your app registration in Azure AD, click on *Manifest*, and modify the groupMembershipClaims property:

```
"groupMembershipClaims": "SecurityGroup",
```

This will result in the Id token containing the user's group ids.
It does have a limit though, only a certain amount of groups can be included, in which case you would have to get them from Graph API instead.

Here is the endpoint you would need to call in that case: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/functions-and-actions#getMemberGroups.

Comment: thank you.
I have actually already set this, but am not seeing any further info when I check the token and return userinfo. Am I missing something? I added all the graph permissions afaik. Thanks again.

Comment: I will post a screen shot tomorrow when working, if possible on here.

Comment: The only options that appear are;
AccessToken
AccessTokenType
Authority
ExpiresOn
ExtendedLifeTimeToken
IdToken
TenantId
UserInfo

Comment: IdToken just contains the bearer token by the looks

Comment: Have you tried to deserialize the id token at e.g. https://jwt.ms? It should contain the group ids.

Comment: wow. not used that before. thank you. I deserialize and got a ton of info, but no groups. One item does jump out, the tid of the user, so I may need to re-query the graph api and get info from this? Is this normal routine? Thanks so much. Scott

Comment: If you set the setting I mentioned in the answer, the group ids should be there under a `groups` claim. Yes, another way is to query from graph API, in which case you would need the tenant id (which is the tid), and the user's object id (which is the oid).

Comment: not sure why the groups arent coming up. I set this as instructed. "groupMembershipClaims": "SecurityGroup". I think you have set me on the right route. Not sure if the authenication is messing it up. I call from a native app to the api, so both native and Web app / API are present. Thanks for your help.

Comment: web api

"appId": "cxx",
  "appRoles": [],
  "availableToOtherTenants": false,
  "displayName": "xx",
  "errorUrl": null,
  "groupMembershipClaims": "SecurityGroup",
  "optionalClaims": null,
  "acceptMappedClaims": null,

Native.
"appId": "xx",
  "appRoles": [],
  "availableToOtherTenants": true,
  "displayName": "xx",
  "errorUrl": null,
  "groupMembershipClaims": "SecurityGroup",
  "optionalClaims": null,
  "acceptMappedClaims": null,

Comment: Looks okay. Is the user surely in a group?

Comment: yes, though only one. but thats is enough. Odd. Let me not keep you. Thanks for your help on this. I will work forward.Thank you again

Answer (score 1):

to add to @juunas's answer, the following sample [active-directory-dotnet-webapp-groupclaims](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-groupclaims) explains things in details.

In particular [Step 3: Configure your application to receive group claims](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-groupclaims#step-3-configure-your-application-to-receive-group-claims) explains the app configuration in the manifest.

See also the claims related to groups in [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-token-and-claims#claims-in-idtokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-token-and-claims)